# How to find extrema of $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}$ defined on $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1^2 + 2x^2_2 + 3x^2_3 < 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a function $g: U \to\mathbb{R}$ where 
$$U :=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1^2 + 2x^2_2 + 3x^2_3 < 1\}$$ 
and 
$$g(x) = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}$$
I would like to find out if g(x) has any extrema.

---

#### What I've tried so far:

$U$ is an open set. Now I'm looking for $\nabla g(a)$, where $x \in U$.

$$\nabla g(x) = (
\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}},
\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}},
\frac{x_3}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}}
)$$

If I want to get local extrema of $g$ then I have to find $a \in U$ such that $\nabla g(a) = (0,0,0)$.

The only solution I can think of is the $a=(0,0,0)$ point. However, if $x_1, x_2, x_3 = 0$ then $\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x^2_2 + x^2_3}} = \frac{0}{\sqrt{0}}$ which is undefined.

And now I'm stuck.

Comment: The square root is strictly monotone. So why aren't you looking for extrema of $g^2$?

Comment: Since $g((0,0,0))=0$ and $g$ is always positive isn't $(0,0,0)$ a minimum?

Comment: @GBQT, you are right! I don't have to calculate gradient of g(0,0,0). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use Lagrange's multipliers. $g$ just represents the distance from the origin and $U$ is an open ellipsoid that encloses the origin, hence $\min_{x\in U} g(x)=0$ is attained in the origin and $\sup_{x\in U}g(x)=\max_{x\in\text{cl}(U)}g(x) = 1$ is attained at $(\pm 1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

First,
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\le x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^2\lt1
$$
and we can make
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2
$$
as close to $1$ by sending $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\to(1,0,0)$.

Therefore, the supremum is $1$. Of course, the minimum is $0$ at $(0,0,0)$.